# Scope of permitted questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, scope, rules

Being new to Stack Overflow, I'm not entirely familiar with what is or is not permitted.

I'm in the process of developing a web application for a non-profit (at no charge) and thought it might be interesting to get feedback and advice from fellow programmers. What I have in mind far exceeds the "how do I do this?" type of questions one might expect to see.

In fact, I'm not entirely certain how to phrase my question so this will have to suffice. Is it acceptable to seek advice for an entire project?

**Update:** My question is flagged as a possible duplicate of a question that was asked more than a year ago, one that is clearly different. Go figure.

Comment: It's hard to say without the question, but I suspect what you're thinking of asking is **too broad**. SO is for specific, answerable questions; seeking advice leads to vague, opinionated answers.

Comment: Given the scope of my project and the format of StackOverflow, I tend to agree that it might be too broad. However, it might be possible to break it down and ask more specific questions. Would that be more appropriate?

Comment: Again, it's hard to say without seeing the question(s). Generally, design-type questions are better suited to [programmers.se], recommendations for tools to [softwarerecs.se] and specific issues with implementation to SO.

Comment: The fact you can't be more precise yet kinda shows that you don't know what you'll be asking AT ALL. I'd suggest figuring out the first couple questions you would have, and coming to Meta with those. The vagueness in your post makes it look as if you're about to ask "I'm doing a website for X, what do you think I should know before I start" which is definitely not a good fit

Comment: Most of the design phase is already complete and I have created a fully functional prototype. Mostly what I'm looking to do is refine and optimize the scripts which are currently a mixture of JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: @Patrice I can be as precise as you want to be so you shouldn't make assumptions. I have a very clear objective and know exactly what I want to achieve. The only thing I am not yet clear about is exactly how to achieve it. If I knew that, there would be no need for advice.

Comment: @David Your question here says :"I'm not entirely certain how to phrase my question so this will have to suffice", so I assumed that you're not at all sure what you'll ask about. I worked with what you gave (ie: not much). If you have very clear questions, it can work. Now, you say "refine and optimize", so it might be better suited for Code review (NOTE: please go read each sister site's on topic, I'm not fully familiar with CodeReview's). For the rest, "how to achieve X" is a slippery slope to "too broad of a question" so it depends on how it's phrased

Comment: @Patrice I was vague, not only because I was not clear about how to phrase the question, but also because I did not want to unintentionally skew the nature of any responses I might receive. I completely agree that it would be pointless to ask how to do something without providing specifics. In this case, I was simply trying to wade into the waters before jumping in with both feet.

Comment: If you have working code that you think could be improved, perhaps consider [codereview.se]?

Comment: In the interest of clarity, I also have to be careful about providing too many specifics because I am bound by a non disclosure agreement that prevents me from disclosing certain information. Thus, caution (on my part) is warranted.

Comment: BTW: This is off-topic but I'm unclear about something. What is the point of "votes"? It seems like something a little too easy to exploit, or perhaps there is a higher purpose?

Comment: Hover over the vote buttons for a hint about their purpose.  FYI, there's a pretty extensive help page for each site on the SE network.  If you haven't read them on the sites you were thinking about posting on, do that.

Comment: @Will Most things have an intended purpose, but how they are used in reality is often very different. Personally, I have never been a fan of gamification systems, but like they say...when in Rome.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the community is pretty good at spotting [sockpuppets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/new/sock-puppets?show=all&sort=newest). More info on [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation). Note that [voting on meta is (sometimes) different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187018/voting-on-meta-is-not-just-for-disagreement-update-the-help-center-to-reflect).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I place online "votes" in the same category as "likes"... utterly useless. Nothing against SO, but that is how I have always felt, long before I knew that SO even existed, and I see no compelling reason to change my belief.

Comment: Apart from the gamification aspect (about whose limitations and weaknesses we have truckloads of past discussion; most folks tend to view it like Churchill viewed Democracy, I think), votes have one real-world purpose here,  quality control. Unanswered questions with negative votes will be automatically cleaned up after a while; users who garner a substantial number of downvotes on their posts may eventually be blocked from asking further questions. At 10,000+ new questions a day, a necessary protection for our collective sanity.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I understand the rationale for using "votes", it's just that my experiences garnered from such systems have usually been more negative than positive.

Comment: My comment was in response to yours from 2 hours ago where you said, *What is the point of "votes"? It seems like something a little too easy to exploit, or perhaps there is a higher purpose?* I wasn't trying to talk you into anything, just provide info. You don't actually have to vote if you don't want to.

Comment: @BSMP I understand, and tried to reciprocate. It's a slippery slope and I am fully aware that my personal opinion will change nothing so I'm going to leave it at that.

Comment: `my experiences garnered from such systems have usually been more negative than positive` mine, too - until Stack Overflow. That is not to say that voting is not a wildly unreliable measure for *anything*, but overall it works reasonably well around here, I don't know why really

Comment: @Pekka웃  I'm new here, so I will try and not pass judgement until I have seen voting in action at StackOverflow first hand. Based on my past experiences, it will not be easy to change my opinion, but I will keep an open mind.

Comment: There is one positive note about my brief experience here, aside from getting answers, despite being new I have yet to be called a "noob" outright. Having been a programmer for more than 20 years, it always gets me a little riled up. ;)

Comment: @David oh, I think you will hate voting when you see it in action. At least occasionally :) But from a long term perspective, the place is still an amazingly much more high quality resource than you would expect from the underlying system. Either way, I'm sure you will be a welcome addition to the place, regardless whether your first set of questions will turn out to be on topic or not! Someone who is thoughtful enough to ask on Meta before asking is very likely to be a quality contributor in the future. (If you choose to *be* a contributor, that is, of course.)

Comment: Should you actually get called a "noob" or anything else, do feel free to flag the comment. (Hover over the upper left hand space next to a comment and you'll see an up arrow for voting and a flag below it.) I wish I could say everyone is so well behaved you won't need it but moderators will take care of problems.

Comment: @BSMP I've been called a "noob" so many times that I mostly laugh it off now, especially if the person who said it is obviously full of it. Based on many comments I read in the weeks before actually joining SO, I believe that many people could use a few lessons in tact and perhaps even manners, but that's the internet. Gotta take the good with the bad.

Comment: @Pekka웃 While the jury is still out about "votes", I'm starting to dislike "flagging". Especially the infinite loop known as "Possible duplicate of", which can apply to just about anything. Don't like a question, flag it. In my opinion, it's a great way of discouraging good questions, rather than encouraging them. As a matter of fact, I was working on a very specific and highly detailed question when the second "flag" to this question came in, which only made me think twice about posting it.

Comment: @David it's not as bad as it sounds, and a pretty cool QA tool, too. It takes 5 people to vote a question as a duplicate (or off-topic, or too broad, etc.) On SO proper that works fairly well overall. Here on Meta, we're a bit more liberal in what can be voted to be a duplicate of something else, but I agree the two votes on this question weren't necessary. Will vote to reopen. But even with this, you arguably got good input on your question

Answer (score 10):

No, that would not be an appropriate SO question.  It would be, at a minimum, Too Broad.

Answer (score 2):

If you've written code, ***and it works***, but you want specific feedback about,

> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases

in a section/module/function then [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the site to ask the question. If, however, you don't have working code and your question pertains to

> - software requirements
> - software architecture and design
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - quality assurance and testing
> - development methodologies and processes
> - software configuration management
> - software engineering management
> - software licensing

then you're probably better off on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as long as your question is focused on a relatively narrow section of the overall application.

If you have a specific, practical problem, typically about a bug or implementation detail, as in

> I've done X, but Y happens when I really want Z.

or

> I'm trying to use the `Foo` method of BarLib, but it only takes an object of type `Fubar`. I tried some code for converting a `Foo` to a `Fubar` as provided by the `BarFooConverter` class, but the property `X` isn't being converted. How do I `fubar` my `Foo`?

then SO is the right place for the question.

Note that every site in the network has a page at:

```
{site}/help/on-topic
```

that tells you what kinds of questions are allowed on each site. For example, ours is at [stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: CR and programmers could potentially discuss those types of issues about *a particular piece of the application* that is sufficiently narrowed in scope, but discussing *the entire application* is almost certainly going to be too broad on either of those sites as well.

Comment: @Servy - Good point, added some clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful and informative answer, it's much better than the typical "go look it up" answers I see far too often. Your answer also illustrates something that I didn't think of until this moment, it was not immediately obvious that any other "sections" existed other than StackOverflow itself. Perhaps some SO interface design changes are in order?

Comment: @David, you'll find an entire network of sites at [se], all of them go by the same principle of a Repository of Quality Q&A's. Familiarizing yourself with the interface and the modus operandi would be better than proposing design changes. Every site has a Help section where you can get to know the scope and specifics of each site. And every one of them has a Meta site where you can clear doubts about how they work. And welcome to the Stack :)

Comment: @David - Top left corner of all pages. Click "Stack Exchange" to open the dropdown. There's a list of all SE sites.

Comment: Force of habit. Part of my job is to critique and propose design changes, in addition to good old fashioned programming. As for Meta... I asked before I acted, thats gotta count for something.

Comment: Well, I've given it some thought, in addition to reading the "help" links provided, and I have come to a conclusion about how to address questions regarding my project. Specifics they want, specifics I got... when the time comes.

Comment: It's funny, but I tried posting on the Programmers forum as suggested,  and I actually think I heard crickets chirping. Four views in over an hour and I'm pretty sure they were all mine from refreshing the page to see if there were any answers or comments. I gave up waiting and deleted the post.